# PackagesNotFoundError for pyttsx in Anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, spyder

I have made multiple attempts but can't find a fix to the following. This is being done with Anaconda.

```
conda install pyttsx
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - pyttsx

Current channels:

  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-32
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-32
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-32
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

Comment: Try this: conda install -c auto pyttsx

Comment: I got the same response as above

Comment: What Operating System (and bits, like Win-32 or Win-64) and CPU you have? Might be the case that package not available for your software/hardware combination.

Answer (score 0):

If you search for a package name on anaconda.org you can find out what channel(s) it is available on (which may not be in the default anaconda channel).  In this case:

```
$ conda install -c auto pyttsx
```

See https://anaconda.org/auto/pyttsx

I should add: It appears this package has not been updated in over 6 years, and is only available for Python 2.7.  So you should consider whether it is a good idea to use it and if there isn't a better, currently maintained alternative.